Optimización de requests a Firestore
antes que nada aclaro que soy un novato en desarrollo web, con lo cual hay muchas cosas que aún ignoro. Mi pregunta es más bien conceptual más que de código.
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web en NextJS que renderiza posts en diferentes páginas. Los usuarios tienen la posibilidad de aplicar uno o mas filtros para hacer las requests a una colección que contiene los documentos en Firestore. Ya tengo todo eso desarrollado y funcionando, pero ahora estoy buscando como optimizar el numero de peticiones, ya que que según entiendo firebase cobra por cantidad de requests.
Lo que hace mi aplicación es, cuando el usuario está en la primera página trae los primeros 20 posts, en la segunda los siguientes 20 posts y así sucesivamente. Ahora si yo vuelvo a la página 1 desde la 2, vuelve a hacer la solicitud de los primeros 20 posts, con lo cual a
mi criterio no es óptimo, por ello estoy analizando la posibilidad de cachear en memoria los posts que fueron solicitados y si vuelvo a una página anterior tomarlos desde allí y NO volver a hacer la request.
Es en este punto donde tengo dudas sobre que estrategia tomar para hacer esto de la forma más eficiente. Entiendo que cada enfoque obviamente tiene pros y contras. La primera opción que me viene a la mente es ir agregando los posts a un estado redux, por ejemplo en un array de arrays:
[
  [{...}, {...}, ... ,{...}], //Posts page 1
  [{...}, {...}, ... ,{...}], //Posts page 2
  [{...}, {...}, ... ,{...}], //Posts page 3
  ...
  [{...}, {...}, ... ,{...}]  //Posts page n
]

¿Es esta opción recomendable? Supongamos que en mi colección de documentos hay miles y miles de posts, y hay un usuario que navega y navega y sigue solicitando posts, haciendo que este array se vuelva muy grande, esto impacta en la performance de la app, es decir se empieza
a poner lenta o puede generar algún tipo de inconveniente?
Si este enfoque no es el adecuado, cual podría ser una opción razonable para cachear los posts de Firestore?
Toda sugerencia u opinión es bienvenida. Gracias de antemano.

Hola. Puedes implementar la paginación con cursores de consulta. Lee aquí para más detalles. Sea como sea, tu pregunta se basa en opiniones y podría terminar cerrada, sobre todo porque lo que en un contexto puede ser adecuado, en otro no lo es y eso escapa de las posibilidades de quien vaya a responder a tu pregunta. Investiga lo que sea mejor para tu caso y cuando tengas en código y alguna dificultad con él entonces sí podremos ayudarte.

Entendido. Es una pregunta demasiado genérica. Gracias por la respuesta.

Que versión de nextjs estas usando y que método usas para solicitar los datos?  fetch, reactQuery, etc...?

La versión de next que estoy utilizando es la 13.2.4 y para obtener el array de objetos de firestore directamente hago una consulta limitada con la función query(), con cursores, y luego al resultado de eso se pasa a la función getDocs() también de Firestore.
